# Js Возможно ли получить разрешение видео из input?

Tags: javascript, input, видео, width

Я могу узнать разрешение(ширину и/или высоту) изображения из input следующим кодом:

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(input[0].files[0]);
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
    alert(img.width);
};
img.src = url;
```

Как узнать разрешение (ширину и/или высоту) видео(mp4) из input при помощи JS/jquery?

Comment: [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кому вдруг понадобится, то я нашел решение:

```
var scr = URL.createObjectURL(input[0].files[0]);
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(e){
    var width = this.videoWidth;
    var height = this.videoHeight;
    var duration = this.duration; //длительность видео в секундах
});
video.src = scr;
```

Comment: после конвертирования исходного видео на ПК в другое разрешение (при помощи программы FormatFactory), скрипт выдавать ширину и высоту равную 0, хотя, видео не битое. оказалось дело в Codec видео. Проблему решил изменив codec при конвертации на AVI. Я это к тому, что если у вас выдает ширину и высоту 0x0 поэксперементируйте с форматом кодировки. При помощи вышеупомянутой проги это можно сделать. В общем, я в этом не шарю, просто имейте ввиду. Мне скрипт нужен чисто для себя, так что меня устраивает